# Tkinter removing buttons gets error list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter, graphics

The problem that I am currently having is that in removing the widgets from the window, I get an error saying list index out of range and does not remove all of the widgets. I have looked all over the place for answers but have not found any that have my problem.

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import subprocess as sub
from sys import platform
import time
from threading import *
from pathlib import Path
import ugmfunctions

def rmvusrgrubutton(widget):
    #scrip = scriptrunnerGUI()
    #print(scrip.usrd)
    #scrip.usrd = 1
    #print(scrip.usrd)
    print(widget)
    print('Removing User / Group Settings buttons')
    #scrip.usrgru()
    widget.grid_remove()

def chngTOusr():
    scrip = scriptrunnerGUI()
    print(scrip.usrd)
    print(scrip.mmd)
    scrip.usrd = 0
    scrip.mmd = 1
    print(scrip.usrd)
    print(scrip.mmd)
    scrip.usrgru()

def rmvmmbuttons():
    scrip = scriptrunnerGUI()
    print(scrip.mmd)
    scrip.mmd = 1
    print(scrip.mmd)
    print('Removing main menu buttons...')
    scrip.mmenu()

def chngTOmm():
    scrip = scriptrunnerGUI()
    print(scrip.mmd)
    print(scrip.usrd)
    scrip.mmd = 0
    scrip.usrd = 1
    print(scrip.mmd)
    print(scrip.usrd)
    scrip.usrgru()


def doNothing():
    print('I do nothing')

class scriptrunnerGUI():
    ssh = ''
    ftp = ''
    proftpd = ''
    vsftpd = ''
    web = ''
    apaweb = ''
    nginweb = ''
    smb = ''
    sql = ''
    rsnc = ''
    buttons = []
    usrgrubuttons = []
    usrd = 0
    mmd = 0
    fconf = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.mmenu()

    def mmenu(self):
        print('In Main Menu')
        self.header = Label(text='Main Menu')
        self.header.config(font=18, background='lightblue')
        self.header.grid(row=0)#, sticky='WE')

        buttonNames = ['Search For Prohibited Media', 'Updates', 'User / Group Settings', 'Firewall Settings', 'Services Settings', 'Malware Removal', 'Audit System', 'Basic Configurations', 'Remove Prohibited Software']


        #commands = [thred.threaderSRCH, thred.threaderUPDT, chngTOusr, thred.threaderFWL, thred.threaderServ, thred.threaderMALREM, thred.threaderALYN, thred.threaderBASEconf, thred.threaderRMproCont]
        # commands = [mmfunc.srchmedia, mmfunc.updates, self.usrgru]
        gridrow = ['5', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4', '3']
        gridcolumn = ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0']

        for i in range(0, 9):
            #try:
            #self.buttons.append(Button(root, text=buttonNames[i], width='40', command=lambda: Thread(target=self.commands[i]).start()))
            self.buttons.append(Button(text=buttonNames[i], width='40', command=self.usrgru))
            if self.mmd == 0:
                self.buttons[i].grid(row=gridrow[i], column=gridcolumn[i], pady='2', padx='5')
            else:
                self.buttons[i].grid_remove()

    def usrgru(self):
        buttonNames = ['Back to Main Menu', 'Add User to System', 'Remove User from System', 'Add Group to System', 'Remove Group from System', 'Add User to Group', 'Remove User from Group', 'List Local Users', 'List Local Groups', 'List Members of Group', 'List the Groups an User is in', 'Change all Users Passwords at Once']
        gridrow = ['7', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6']
        gridcolumn = ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
        self.header2 = Label(text='User and Group Settings')
        thredugm = ugmfunctions.ThreadUGMfunc()
        if self.usrd == 0:

            #print('usrd != 1')
            self.header2.grid(row=0, sticky='WE')
            self.header2.config(font=18, background='lightblue')
            print('In Users and Group Settings')
        else:
            # print('Destroying Header')
            rmvusrgrubutton(self.header2)
            #self.header2.grid_remove()

        for i in range(0, 12):
            if self.usrd == 0:
                self.usrgrubuttons.append(Button(text=buttonNames[i], width='40', command= lambda i=i: thredugm.threader(i)))
                #self.usrgrubuttons.append(Button(text=buttonNames[i], width='40', command=chngTOmm))
                self.usrgrubuttons[i].grid(row=gridrow[i], column=gridcolumn[i], pady='2', padx='5')
            else:
                print(self.usrgrubuttons[i])
                print('starting to delete buttons')
                rmvusrgrubutton(self.usrgrubuttons[i])
###################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # creation of GUI
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Apple CIDR Script Runner')
    if platform == 'win32':
        root.geometry("565x300")
    elif platform == 'darwin':
        root.geometry("735x300")
    else:
        root.geometry("565x350")
    main = scriptrunnerGUI()
    root.mainloop()

####################################################
```

ugmfunctions.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import subprocess as sub
from sys import platform
from threading import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from removalTest import *


class usrGruFunc:
    def addusr():
        rootusr = Tk()
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu' or platform == 'win32':
            useryon = ''
            userlbl = Label(rootusr, text='Would you like to add a user? [yes/no] ')
            userlbl.grid(row='1', column='1', sticky='W')
            usery = Button(rootusr, text='yes')
            usery.grid(row='2', column='1', sticky='W')
            usern = Button(rootusr, text='no')
            usern.grid(row='2', column='1', padx='80', sticky='W')

            command = """read -p 'Would you like to add a user? [y/n] : ' aduseryn
        if [ $aduseryn = 'y' ]; then
            aduser=1
            while [ $aduser = 1 ]; do
                read -p 'What would you like to name this new user? : ' name
                read -p 'Is this user an Admin? [y/n] : ' adminyn
                if [ $adminyn = 'y' ]; then
                    sudo adduser --force-badname $name
                    sudo usermod -a -G sudo $name       #adds user to sudo group
                    sudo usermod -a -G adm $name   #adds user to admin group
                    echo "User ${name} has been created and has been added to admin and sudo groups"
                    echo "User ${name} has been created and has been added to admin and sudo groups
                else
                    sudo useradd $name
                    echo "User ${name} has been added!"
                fi
                read -p 'Would you like to add another user? [y/n] : ' aga
                if [ $aga = 'n' ]; then
                    $aduser=0
                fi
            done
            sleep 1s
        else
            usr_gru
        fi"""

            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')
        rootusr.mainloop()

    def rmuser():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def adgru():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def rmgru():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def adusrtogru():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def rmusrfrogru():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def lslocausr():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def lslocagru():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def lsmemgru():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def lsgruusrin():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

    def chngusrspass():
        if platform == 'debian' or platform == 'ubuntu':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'win32':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        elif platform == 'darwin':
            print('This command is not complete yet')
        else:
            print('This command does not yet support this OS')

targets = [chngTOmm, usrGruFunc.addusr, usrGruFunc.rmuser, usrGruFunc.adgru, usrGruFunc.rmgru, usrGruFunc.adusrtogru, usrGruFunc.rmusrfrogru, usrGruFunc.lslocausr, usrGruFunc.lslocagru, usrGruFunc.lsmemgru, usrGruFunc.lsgruusrin, usrGruFunc.chngusrspass]

class ThreadUGMfunc:
    def threader(self, com):
        try:
            print(targets[com])
            threader = Thread(target=targets[com])
            threader.start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Could not start thread')
```

I have narrowed it down to where in the main.py in the scriptrunnerGUI class under the function usgru, where it says:

```
 for i in range(0, 12):
            if self.usrd == 0:
                self.usrgrubuttons.append(Button(text=buttonNames[i], width='40', command= lambda i=i: thredugm.threader(i)))
                #self.usrgrubuttons.append(Button(text=buttonNames[i], width='40', command=chngTOmm))
                self.usrgrubuttons[i].grid(row=gridrow[i], column=gridcolumn[i], pady='2', padx='5')
            else:
                print(self.usrgrubuttons[i])
                print('starting to delete buttons')
                rmvusrgrubutton(self.usrgrubuttons[i])
```

The code works as intended when the line where the command chngTOmm is active, but when the command is lambda i=i: thredugm.threader(i) it breaks and I get the 'list index out of range error'

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I would prefer to use the lambda command because it runs the commands for all of the other buttons.

Any help on this problem would be great!

Update --------------------

Here is the error output I got:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/Desktop/removalTest.py", line 47, in chngTOmm
    scrip.usrgru()
  File "/home/michael/Desktop/removalTest.py", line 119, in usrgru
    print(self.usrgrubuttons[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Could you show all the error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```py
for i in range(12):
```

have

```py
for i in range(0, len(buttonNames)):
```

It seems as if the user who wrote the code had the 12 there as a hardcoded value for some reason instead of looping through the widgets unregarding if there where twelve of them or not.